# Playframework [Java] Migration from 2.6.6. to 2.7.0 Problems with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, migration

This code worked with play 2.6.6 and Hibernate 4.2.3:

```java
int employeeId=1;
String projectId=123;

int projectSize = jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
      TypedQuery<Table> query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Table WHERE employeeId=:employeeId AND projectId=:projectId", Table.class);
      query.setParameter("employeeId", employeeId);
      query.setParameter("projectId", projectId);

      try
      {
        return query.getResultList().size();
      }
      catch (NoResultException e)
      {
        LOGGER.debug("not found");
        return 0;
      }
});
```

Since I updated to play **2.7.0** and updated the hibernate-dependencies to 5.4.0-Final. This block gives me an exception:

**Exception: unable to find models.Table with id 123**

Is this a bug? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What was your previous version of hibernate?

Comment: Hibernate 4.2.3-Final.

Comment: That is huge hibernate update, did you follow up migration guides? Can you post your hibernate configuration and Table class?

Comment: I just want to update play to 2.7.0. Is a hibernate update mandatory? Or what is the lowest version to choose for hibernate?

Comment: I think that you can keep 4.2.3, but I would recommend take effort and update hibernate as well.

Comment: With Hibernate 4.2.3 I get those exceptions: `CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors`:[PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/nEt1iavu)

Comment: Did you changed java version?

Comment: No. I didn't change the java version.

Comment: You are using java 8, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Hibernate 4.2.8-Final resolved the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should to specify your select in query:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Table t WHERE employeeId=:employeeId AND projectId=:projectId", Table.class);
```

Comment: don't think so. why should this worked in play 2.6??

Comment: well he's right that your JPQL is utterly vendor specific and currently invalid against the JPA spec (aka "HQL" ... go read the JPA spec if not believing). Fixing it to what is specified above doesn't answer your question here though.